# Using $this when not in object context Yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii-components

i have error:

> Using $this when not in object context.

i am using this: [meysampg/intldate](https://github.com/meysampg/intldate)

```
<?php
namespace app\components;
use meysampg\intldate\IntlDateTrait;

    class General extends Component
    {
        use IntlDateTrait;
    public static function jalaliToGregorian($date,$pattern='yyyy/MM/dd')
        {
            echo $date;
            $dateToGre = explode('/',$date);

            echo $this->fromPersian([$dateToGre[0],$dateToGre[1],$dateToGre[2]])->toGregorian('en')->asDateTime($pattern);
        }
    }
```

Comment: there is no `$this` in static methods .. have you tried using OOP instead?

Comment: @tereško This is actually OOP, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: @FMashiro static variables and methods are actually an antithesis to OOP paradigm. When you write static structures, they essentially are "namespaced globals". Static methods are namespaced global function and static variables are just namespaced global variables ... with all the problems associated with them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The static keyword means that that method or variable is not part of the object, but rather part of the class.

Which means that `$this` is not accessible.

Try this:

```
class General extends Component
{
    use IntlDateTrait;
    public static function jalaliToGregorian($date,$pattern='yyyy/MM/dd')
    {
        echo $date;
        $dateToGre = explode('/',$date);
        $general = new General();
        echo $general->fromPersian([$dateToGre[0],$dateToGre[1],$dateToGre[2]])->toGregorian('en')->asDateTime($pattern);
    }
}
```

When referring to a static property or method from within the class, you either need to use `ClassName::Method()` or `self::method()`

And if you wish to call a non-static method/property from within the class, you need to instantiate it.

Comment: now i have error: Non-static method app\components\General::fromPersian() should not be called statically

Comment: @user3770797 Fixed it.

Comment: That's less of a solution and more of a terrible hack :D I would have just made a stand-alone helper function instead (that used an instance of `General` as one of the inputs). Then again, I am honestly afraid even to ask, what is inside a class named "General".

Comment: @tereško this is literally the solution. There is no other one, this is how PHP works, this is how you solve a problem without redoing your architecture.